# Dynamic Canvas Control

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

I would like to change Figure according to selected QRadiobutton. In my real code , I tried various way to do that with and without signal(Also, checked other topics.).
To make it looks less compilcated, I rearrange my code for question.

I hope someone can help me to overcome this situation.

Here is my codes;
***figure.py***

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from numpy import arange, sin, cos, pi


class MainCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Ultimately, this is a QWidget (as well as a FigureCanvasAgg, etc.)."""

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

        t = arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)
        s = sin(2 * pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s, color="red", linestyle="solid")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainCanvas()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***main.py***

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from figure import MainCanvas


class RadioButton(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.main_cavnas = MainCanvas()

        self.InitUi()

    def InitUi(self):
        groups = {"Functions": ("Sinus", "Cosines"),
                  "Colors": ("Red", "Green"),
                  "Line Styles": ("Solid", "Dashed")
                  }

        widget_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        main_group = QGroupBox("Operations")
        main_group_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        for group, buttons in groups.items():
            group_box = QGroupBox(group)
            group_layout = QVBoxLayout()
            for button_text in buttons:
                button = QRadioButton(button_text)
                button.setObjectName("radiobutton_%s" % button_text.lower())
                if button_text == "Sinus" or button_text == "Red" or button_text == "Solid":
                    button.setChecked(True)

                group_layout.addWidget(button)

            group_box.setLayout(group_layout)
            main_group_layout.addWidget(group_box)

        main_group.setLayout(main_group_layout)
        widget_layout.addWidget(self.main_cavnas)
        widget_layout.addWidget(main_group)

        self.setLayout(widget_layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = RadioButton()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You could use matplotlib's widgets, for your case [RadioButtons](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/widgets/radio_buttons.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have more complicated GUI. I just made it basic for my problem. The code that you send can't meet the needs.

Answer (score 2):

The logic is to detect the change of state of the buttons, then obtain the information, clean the canvas and redraw.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import numpy as np


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)

        groups = {
            "Functions": (("Sinus", np.sin), ("Cosines", np.cos)),
            "Colors": (("Red", "red"), ("Green", "green")),
            "Line Styles": (("Solid", "solid"), ("Dashed", "dashed")),
        }

        main_group = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Operations")
        main_group_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(main_group)

        self.group_btns = []

        for group_title, v in groups.items():
            group = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(group_title)
            main_group_layout.addWidget(group)
            vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(group)
            group_btn = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self)
            self.group_btns.append(group_btn)
            for (text, value) in v:
                radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(text)
                radio.setProperty("prop", value)
                vlay.addWidget(radio)
                group_btn.addButton(radio)
                if text in ("Sinus", "Red", "Solid"):
                    radio.setChecked(True)

        for group_btn in self.group_btns:
            group_btn.buttonToggled.connect(self.update_canvas)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.canvas, stretch=1)
        lay.addWidget(main_group)

        self.update_canvas()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def update_canvas(self):
        func, color, style = (
            group.checkedButton().property("prop") for group in self.group_btns
        )
        t = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)
        s = func(2 * np.pi * t)

        self.canvas.figure.clear()
        ax = self.canvas.figure.subplots()
        ax.plot(t, s, color=color, linestyle=style)
        self.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Widget()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for fast answer. Your code actually solved my big part of the problem. Is there a any way to do this for seperate buttons.py and canvas.py files  as I shared in my answer ?

Comment: @Gokberk I think that part is out of the question, it can also be an exercise that helps you understand how to separate logic.

Comment: I updated my code according to your answer. However, I coulnd't figure out how to overcome sending sinus & cosines function. Is there a alternative way to do that or am I missing something